# How Get Data From DataGridvView and send it to parent form on c#?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a search function in my program. when user insert ID and click on search button in main form , The data is taken from database and show on Datagridview on new form.
I want to get selected row from Datagridview and return values to parents form (and set values on textbox,combobox,...) without making a new parent form 
Thanks for your Helps

Comment: Your new form should have a reference back to it's parent form, which you could use to gain access.

Comment: Are you using showdialog when you open you child form?  If so create a member variable  in the child form to hold the results.  Then in the on closing event of the child form enter in the results into that variable.  Then in your main form after the child form returns call the getter for that variable to obtain the results.

Comment: No,I dont use showdialog,its work like this:when user search a name or ID ,child form shown a form with 3 element(Datagridview and 2 button(cancel and submit)) , user select a row and press submit. selected row values must set on parent form . I cant send selected row values to parent form because parent form elements not accessible on child form!I changed element Modifiers to Public, But It doesnt work!Thanks for Your Helps